# Getting a column index in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm pretty new to NumPy and I'm looking for a way to get the index of a current column I'm iterating over in a matrix.

```
import numpy as np

#sum of elements in each column
def p_b(mtrx):
    b = []
    for c in mtrx.T:
        summ = 0
        for i in c:
            summ += i
        b.append(summ)
    return b

#return modified matrix where each element is equal to itself divided by
#the sum of the current column in the original matrix
def a_div_b(mtrx):
    for c in mtrx:
        for i in c:
            #change i to be i/p_b(mtrx)[index_of_a_current_column]
    return mtrx
```

For the input `([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])` the result would be
`([[1/12, 2/12, 3/12], [4/15, 5/15, 6/15], [7/18, 8/18, 9/18]])`.

Any ideas about how I can achieve that?

Comment: read the documentation of numpy.sum function and read about the axis parameter of numpy sum function

Comment: what do you mean by index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need those functions and loops to do that. Those will not be efficient. When using `numpy`, go for vectorized operations whenever is possible (in most cases it is possible). [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules are used to perform mathematical operation between arrays of different dimensions, when possible, such that you can use vectorization, which is much more efficient than python loops.

In your case, say that your array `arr` is:

```
arr = np.arange(1, 10)
arr.shape = (3, 3)

#arr is:
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

you can achieve the desired result with:

```
res = (arr.T / arr.sum(axis=0)).T

>>> res
array([[0.08333333, 0.16666667, 0.25      ],
       [0.26666667, 0.33333333, 0.4       ],
       [0.38888889, 0.44444444, 0.5       ]])
```

[numpy sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) allows you to sum your array along a given axis if the `axis` parameter is given. 0 is the inner axis, the one you want to sum.
`.T` gives the transposed matrix. You need to transpose to perform the division on the correct axis and then transpose back.